# Codeigniter, symfony, composer куда копать, чтобы совместить

Tags: php, codeigniter, symfony, composer

Добрый день, суть проблемы: нужно настроить codeigniter внутри symfony под composer. Подскажите направление в котором необходимо копать чтобы решить данную задачку.

Comment: И самый важный вопрос, зачем вам Фреймворк в фреймворке?

Comment: Это не моя прихоть, такое тестовое задание, при устройстве на работу, пришло.

Comment: Жесть, у этого задания нет смысла... А можете показать постановку задачи? Или то, что вы написали и есть постановка?

Comment: Задача: "Благодарим Вас за отклик на вакансию "PHP-разработчик". Ваше резюме показалось нам очень интересным. Мы хотели бы предложить Вам выполнить простое тестовое задание: 

Нужно настроить codeigniter внутри symfony под composer. База данных - sqlite. На выходе - готовый к деплою через composer архив с гит-репозиторием. Визуально - хелло ворлд-страничка, написанная через codeigniter.
По нашим подсчетам данное задание должно занять не больше одного дня. "

Comment: Это какой-то разрыв шаблона просто... Уточните у них что именно требуется? Может быть они просто так вставили слово Symfony? Просто чтобы отрабатывали контроллеры из codeignitor из symfony, надо нехило покопаться и хорошо знать Symfony

Comment: Видимо на то и расчет, что человек хорошо будет знать эти фреймворки. Хотя в интернете вообще нет упоминания о подобной возможности настройки, то ли это не типовая какая то задача на сообразительность, то ли это бесполезное занятие. Не знаю, в общем я им уже отписался, что не справился.

Comment: тут еще перла и 1с не хватает)), а ну и чтобы при открытии станицы смс сообщение отправлялось на com порт, ну это уже на c++ желательно). Может они просто проверяют, готовность программиста браться  за любые задачи?)

Answer (score 1):

задача может решена через многие "костыли" и долго копаясь. так как одно будет мешать другому, скорее всего задачка на логику.... тут просто надо привет-страничку сделать и все....

ТОЛЬКО настроить **CI** с *helloworld* страничкой и засовываеш это в неработающий, но со всеми файлами SF. Будет  ли оно дальше работать и как они будут в нем работать дальше - это уже их проблема.